# Oracle CONNECT BY behaviour

Tags: oracle, connect-by

I thought I understand how Oracle's `CONNECT BY` works.

But then I found this.

```
select dual.*, CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE from dual
connect by nocycle 1=1
and LEVEL <= 2
;
```

results in

```
DUMMY   CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE
X       0
X       0
```

but

```
select dual.*, CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE from dual
connect by nocycle 1=1
and LEVEL <= 2
and prior dummy = dummy
;
```

produces only 1 row

```
DUMMY   CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE
X       1
```

I expected same result as in the first query.

Can someone please explain or point me to an explanation of this?

This is on `Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How does Oracle identify "cycles" in a hierarchical query?

If it's documented, it's not done very well. Anyway, I think we found the correct and complete (and, really, pretty simple) answer in an OTN discussion: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3999985

Anyway: When you run a hierarchical query, for each row generated, Oracle will look at the columns **that are operated upon by the PRIOR operator** in the `connect by` clause, and ONLY to those columns, to see if a newly generated row matches an already existing one.

This is why "select 5 from dual connect by level <= 100" works, even though it generates the same row 100 times. There is no cycle, because "cycle" only looks at columns preceded by PRIOR in CONNECT BY - and there are none.

This is also why you will often see things like `connect by [other conditions here] and prior sys_guid() is not null`. `sys_guid()` will never be null; but by adding it to `connect by`, and very importantly with the `PRIOR` operator, you make sure there will never be cycles (because each call is guaranteed to return a different value!) so you are free to break "infinite recursion" by conditions on `level` or other means, but not by the identification of "cycles". (Due to this extra "column" to check, Oracle will never see a cycle.)

Comment: this is a very useful link, thanks. I wonder if it's documented somewhere (lack of documentation may indicate it's subject to an unannounced change).